# Не работает регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть лог файл, в котором есть куча строк. В каждой -- подстрока типа **`REFER_ID=575616`**.

Хочу вытащить все id рефералов используя код

```
ereg("(REFER_ID=\d*)", $str, $regs);
```

В `$regs` заносится только "`REFER_ID=`" без цифр.

Если в регулярном выражении заменить на "`REFER_ID=\d*`" , то `$regs` не формируется вообще (проверял кодом **`isset ($regs)? print 1:print 0;`**)

Где я не прав?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно так:

```
$a='REFER_ID=575611
REFER_ID=575612
REFER_ID=575613
REFER_ID=575614
';
preg_match_all ('/REFER_ID=(\d+)/',$a,$m);
print_r($m);
```

тогда в $m[1] будет массив всех ID
вот такой:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => REFER_ID=575611
            [1] => REFER_ID=575612
            [2] => REFER_ID=575613
            [3] => REFER_ID=575614
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 575611
            [1] => 575612
            [2] => 575613
            [3] => 575614
        )

)
```

Comment: Попробовал preg_match_all("/REFER_ID=(\d+)/", $str, $matches);
Получился пустой массив типа Array([0]=>Array()[1]=>Array())
P.s. А как код программы вставить в сообщение?

Comment: у тебя пропущен слэш: не `(d+`, а `(\d+`

Comment: просто вставляй и потом  выдели его и нажми кнопочку с ноликами и единичками

Comment: В конечном счёте получается вполне работоспособный код, но почему-то регулярное выражение не хавается :(
Про слеш ты конечно загнул: это движок сайта его спрятал.

Comment: В общем ошибку нашёл ещё зимой: preg_match_all был в цикле и $matches перезаписывался пустам результатом поиска. Изменил на $matches[] заработало как надо.